# Unable to assign variable value in model constructor

Tags: php, laravel

I am playing with Laravel models and I need one to return a value that is not in the db table but it comes by running a model method. This method runs a query that groups and count grouped results.

The model method works just fine but I don't seem to be able to pre-fill the $quantity variable within the constructor with something different than 0.

So this is an excerpt of the model:

```
public $quantity;

function __construct($attributes = array(), $exists = false) {
    parent::__construct($attributes, $exists);
    $this->quantity = $this->quantity();
}

public function quantity()
{
    $query = DB::table('carts_shopping')
            ->select('cart_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS quantity'))
            ->where('cart_id',$this->cart_id)
            ->groupBy('cart_id')
            ->first();
    return ($query) ? $query->quantity : 0;
}
```

While this is how I am trying to retrieve the results from controller:

```
$cartitems = Auth::user()->cartshopping;

foreach ($cartitems as $cartitem)
{
    echo $cartitem->name;
    echo $cartitem->quantity;
}
```

As you may guess 'cartshopping' comes from the user model being related with the model excerpt I pasted.

I also noticed that quantity() method gets called and it returns 0 all the time as if $this->cart_id was empty and, changing $this-cart_id with a real value the query itself doesn't even get executed.

Thanks a lot for any suggestion you guys can share.

Comment: Have you tried var_dump($query); just before return? It may not contain what you think it does, or it may, in fact be 0.

Comment: Just tried: unfortunately dd($query); returns NULL.
Same results setting ->where('cart_id',23) with '23' being a known value.

Comment: Then your query is not returning any results.

Comment: I know it is not returning any results! :) The point is: if I comment out the constructor and call the method as follows:

    echo $cartitem->quantity();

results are returned just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried accessing the properties using $this->attributes?

```
public $quantity;

function __construct($attributes = array(), $exists = false) {
    parent::__construct($attributes, $exists);
    $this->quantity = $this->quantity();
}

public function quantity() {
    $query = DB::table('carts_shopping')
            ->select('cart_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS quantity'))
            ->where('cart_id', $this->attributes['cart_id'])
            ->groupBy('cart_id')
            ->first();
    return ($query) ? $query->quantity : 0;
}
```

Failing that, you could try using the Eloquent accessors, which would be the best way to do it. This would make it dynamic as well, which could be useful.

```
class YourModel {

    // Normal model data here

    public function getQuantityAttribute() {
        $query = DB::table('carts_shopping')
            ->select('cart_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS quantity'))
            ->where('cart_id', $this->attributes['cart_id'])
            ->groupBy('cart_id')
            ->first();
        return ($query) ? $query->quantity : 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort Ollieread, just tried and it results in raising the exception: Undefined index: cart_id. I'm wondering if the issue resides somewhere else in the way Laravel builds the model and the constructor gets called.

Concerning the Eloquent accessors, that was my first thought but I understood just later from the Laravel docs that they are used to 'transform your model attributes when getting or setting them.' while my $quantity attribute doesn't exist on the model itself... I'm just calculating it myself hence the method. Have I misunderstood the accessors chapter?

Comment: Accessors can be used in that fashion, but they can also be used to add attributes that don't exist. The above code I gave could be wrapped to make sure that $this->attributes['cart_id'] exists, but it should work. To give you an example, I have `active` int(1) in my tables, but I have getIsActiveAttribute() accessors which will return booleans for $model->is_active. Try removing your custom constructor and making sure the object exists before hand.

Comment: All right... switching to the "accessors" techniques worked like a charm. Now I have my ->quantity returning the proper results but I did not use the $this->attributes['cart_id'] trick, $this->cart_id worked just fine.

Comment: Well you can mark the answer as accepted, and mark the comment as useful if you'd like :) I'm glad it worked, happy to help :D

Comment: There you go. You saved me from pulling my hair... so thanks a lot! :)